# Fetching date from parse db returns undefined

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am in a bit of an issue, after fetching a row using query.first(), i want to access the field codeExpiry from by db and compare it with the date and time right now. The fetched date always logs as undefined.

Here's the code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("SmsCodeVerification", function(request, response) {

    console.log("Code from User: " +request.params.code);

    var id = request.params.userId;

    var userQuery = new Parse.Query("User");
    userQuery.equalTo("objectId", id);

    var object = {};

    var temp = userQuery.first().then(function(result){

        object = result.toJSON();

        console.log("Code expiry from database: " + **object.codeExpiry**);

        var date = new Date();

        var exp = **object["codeExpiry"];**

        console.log("Date of received code: " + date);

        console.log("Expiry: " + exp);

        if(object.cellVerificationCode == request.params.code){

            console.log(+exp+ " Expiry Date,");
            console.log(+date+ " Current Date,");

                if(exp > date){

                    response.success("Code expiry date has passed. The system will now generate a new code.");

                } else {

                    console.log("Code Received.");

                    result.set("isCellNoVerified", true);

                    result.save(null, { useMasterKey: true }).then(function() {
                            response.success("Save Successful.");

                            }, function(error){
                                response.error(error);  
                    }); 
                }
            } else {

                response.error("Code not recognized.");
            }       

    }); 

    temp.then(function(){

        console.log("End of execution!!");
    });

});
```

Here, Object.codeExpiry and result.codeExpiry always logs as undefined or [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

The name of the parse user class `Parse.User`, not "User".  Initialize the query as:

```
 var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
```